# CSS solution to positioning Span element on a Table element

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to position a span element relative to the upper-right corner of a table object.

This table may be wider or move around based on what the user does on the tool, so I was looking for something simpler than the jQuery.position method. I was hoping to do something elegant with CSS.

I've built a small example of my dilemma in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xerf/ZSGfc/

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Stuff 1</td>
                <td>Stuff 2</td>
                <td>Stuff 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stuff 1</td>
                <td>Stuff 2</td>
                <td>Stuff 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stuff 1</td>
                <td>Stuff 2</td>
                <td>Stuff 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <span>&times;</span>
</div>
```

Below are the CSS Styles

```
body
{
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
}

th
{
    padding: 6px;
}

td
{
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Added some images to show required positions:

[image: Scenario 1]

Needs to be where the red Square appears above

Comment: when you say "position relative to upper-right" what exactly does that mean? Do you want to put it on the upper right corner? or just use that as a reference point to position it? (in which case `position: relative` should work, thouh that might use the bottom left, can't remember)

Comment: Thomas, understand my ambiguity. Hopefully my updates help explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrapped your span in a div and placed it in the `<th>` with your title:

```
 <th colspan="3"><div id="container">Title
                    <span>&times;</span></div></th>
```

css:

```
#container{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
```

## Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSGfc/6/

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way would be to simply add another row to the very top of the table, removing its left, top and right borders. Then move your span so that it is contained by this new row and align the text to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `div` or adding another `div` that will control the width of the table, and then have the table inherit the width of that div. From there make the `div`'s `position` property set to relative. Then you can absolutely position the `span` on the `div`.

Something similar to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/eRdeb/1/). With some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div{ 
    position:relative;
    width: XXXpx;
}
table{
    width: XXXpx;
}
span{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an additional table cell on top with `colspan="3"` and `text-align:right` would work.